# What do the values for gitlab's predefiner variable CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE mean?

Tags: gitlab

In the gitlab documentation you find a list of predefined variables [HERE](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html), where the variable `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` is explained to have the possible values "push, web, schedule, api, external, chat, webide, merge_request_event, external_pull_request_event, parent_pipeline, trigger, or pipeline."

However, it is not explained, what they mean.

- push: When you push something to a branch?
- web: When you trigger a pipeline from the web GUI?
- schedule: When a pipeline is triggered by a schedule
- api: When the pipeline is triggered by an API request
- external: ???
- chat: ???
- webide: ???
- merge_request_event: Seems to be triggered when a merge request is created. Does not trigger when a change is actually merged
- external_pull_request_event: ???
- parent_pipeline: ???
- trigger: ???
- pipeline: another pipeline?

If someone knows where the documentation for that is hiding, I appreciate if you can let me know where to find it.

In addition, how can I figure out when some changes are actually merged into a branch? How can I trigger a pipeline in that event?

Comment: `In addition, how can` please one question per question ;) When I can't find documentation, sources are the documentation. https://gitlab.com/search?search=CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE&group_id=9970&project_id=278964&scope=&search_code=true&snippets=false&repository_ref=master&nav_source=navbar will give a lot of hints.

Comment: additionally https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules have links to further explanations about the different states

Comment: If I set a rule $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" and create a tag, would my job be created on tag pipeline or not?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Regarding your first set of questions, i have to point you forward to the gitlab CI Documentation and the `rules:if` section. They have their a good explanation of the states and also some addtion https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules - i am just screenshoting this, so people can relate to it in the future if the link gets outdated:

[image: CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE]

Regarding your additional question:

A merge is a push. We do not check on some branches for `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` but for the branch name and do checks simply against that like:

```yaml
    rules:
        - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
        - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
        - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^release.*$/i'
        - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```

This works eg perfectly in our case for gitflow. But you can vary your rules and easily define them to your own needs - the rules documentation gives a lot of good examples see: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules